# PreparedStatement clearParameters() in a batch

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I have the following code snippet -

```
String sql = "insert into A (c1, c2, c3) values (?, ?, ?)";
Connection connection = new getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

for (Employee employee: employees) {

    ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
    ps.setString(2, employee.getCity());

   if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(employee.getPhone()))
   {
       ps.setString(3, employee.getPhone());
   }
   else
   {
       // add a warning log - I do not want to throw an exception 
       ps.clearParameters();
       continue;
   }
    ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
```

Would the above work and not add that particular employee record to the batch? I tried to reproduce this but was not sure about the results since I do not have access to some of the systems. I read through the description for clearParameters() and it does indicate what happens in a batch scenario. Does it remove the parameters only for that particular record? If it depends on the underlying driver, I use H2 database.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK `clearParameters()` should clear all the currently set parameters so calling `addBatch()` right after this should fail. Setting a parameter overwrites the current value while not doing so keeps the previous value and would cause it to be set in multiple batches (e.g. calling `addBatch()` twice in a row would cause the same set of parameters to be used twice).

Comment: In your case you always set parameters 1 and 2 and if parameter 3 is empty you clear them again. Why not set all parameters only if `getPhone()` returns a non-blank string?

Comment: @Thomas I could do this, but what happens when this is for the 100th record. Will all the parameters for the previous 99 records be unset? I also have a continue in the else block which should ideally clear the parameters for that record and proceed to the next one?

Comment: No any parameters already added as a batch should still be present. As for the `continue`: this just starts a new iteration of the loop, it won't do anything else, i.e. the parameters would not be cleared if you'd not call  `clearParameters()` before that.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what your real question is... if you don't add something to the batch, then obviously, it is not part of the batch, so it won't get executed when you execute the batch. And `clearParameters` doesn't clear the batch, otherwise `clearBatch` wouldn't exist. Please try to reword or clarify your question. And I agree with Thomas, it would be better to just not set parameter values if you are going to skip: perform the check at the start of the loop.

Comment: @Thomas I understand what you wrote now. I know what the continue does. It's just that I wasn't sure about the clearParameters(). I was probably confused with the wording.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, yes I will do that in my code. Thanks